# Dynamic css grid with custom styling for odds/even rows

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to get familiar to CSS grid system. However, right now I'm struggling trying to figure out how to build a dynamic grid that will have custom style for odds/even rows.

So basically I want to implement this pattern for a nx2 grid:

```
[     lg-item     ] [ sm-item ]
[ sm-item ] [     lg-item     ]
[     lg-item     ] [ sm-item ]
.
.
.
```

Where rows will always start either with a large item or a small item

The 100% success for me will also be when this grid can automatically resize whenever viewport has enough width size to hold another element in the same row. Example:

```
Small screen:
[     lg-item     ] [ sm-item ]
[ sm-item ]   [     lg-item     ]
[     lg-item     ] [ sm-item ]
.
.
.
Med screen:
[     lg-item     ] [ sm-item ]  [     lg-item     ]
[ sm-item ]  [     lg-item     ]  [ sm-item ]
[     lg-item     ] [ sm-item ]  [     lg-item     ]
.
.
.
Lg screen:
[     lg-item     ] [ sm-item ]  [     lg-item     ]   [ sm-item ]
[ sm-item ]  [     lg-item     ]  [ sm-item ]  [     lg-item     ]
[     lg-item     ] [ sm-item ]  [     lg-item     ]   [ sm-item ]
.
.
.
```

The thing is that it doesn't matter in which item it ends. Rows will always start with small or large item and it alternates between rows

I'm plain new with this so right now i only have this:

```
    <div class="search-by__inner-container">
        <div class="search-by__item">
            Flavour
        </div>
        <div class="search-by__item">
            Size
        </div>
        <div class="search-by__item">
            New
        </div>
        <div class="search-by__item">
            bundle
        </div>
    </div>
```

SCSS:

```
    .search-by__inner-container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;
        grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
        gap: .8rem;

    }
    .search-by__item{
        background: red;
        padding: 1.5rem;
    }
```

Which only gives me Something like this:

[image]

I don't know if there's a way to reverse my row (like Flex prop) or if I should think of another way to figure this out. On top of this, my desire is to dynamically add these items and they will automatically fit to this grid system.

Can someone give me some hints in order to figure this out?

Comment: CSS Grid alone is not ideal for this, as it is designed for when you know the dimensions of your desired layout. You'll either need to use flexbox entirely, or combine it with grid to achieve this.

Comment: I first tried with Flexbox but then i came to the problem of figuring out items pattern, since is not something like "all odd/even items behave this way" and after trying some alternatives my code just went awful and messy and i thought about quitting that idea and trying with css grid @TylerH

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updated to stripe the rows in addition to alternating sizes.

You could achieve the alternating rows and sizes with [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), and adapt to different screen sizes via [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries):

```css
.container {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 8px;
}

.container > * {
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  padding: 8px;
  color: skyblue;
}

/* alternate large/small item order per row */
.container > *:nth-child(4n + 1),
.container > *:nth-child(4n + 4) {
  background: aliceblue;
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}

/* alternate background color per row */
.container > *:nth-child(4n + 1),
.container > *:nth-child(4n + 2){
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>  
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>  
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>  
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>  
</ul>
```

```css
grid-column: auto / span 2;
```

The [grid-column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column) property is specifying that each item that matches the selector should start at its natural column position ("auto") and it should occupy 2 columns instead of one ("span 2").

Comment: This appears to just apply different coloring only to large items (wherever they are), instead of entire rows when those rows are even or odd.

Comment: I thought you want to alternate long/short items per row. If you just want every other row then update the nth-child rules accordingly.

Comment: NB - I'm not OP, just commenting based on my interpretation of the question. The problem is that the number of items in the rows needs to be dynamic, so you cannot rely on `nth-child` criteria using a grid-based layout.

Comment: This looks interesting. Can you walk me through grid-column property value? I don't get that. However, this works for fixed grid size. What if you want more columns if viewport allows it? that's the other thing that i can't figure out

Comment: @TylerH Oh. Sorry. Guess I should re-read the question. I get ahead of myself sometimes.

Comment: @FrankPonte updated my answer with an explanation of the grid-column rule.

Comment: I'm marking this answer as solution because it solved half of my problem and its an awesome solution proposal. For dynamic rows i think i'm just gonna put some media queries and not overthink too much this. Thank you for helping me out @rayhatfield. You rock, man! Edit: I just saw you propose media queries solution already, which is what makes more sense haha.

Comment: When making a table with CSS grid, you can wrap the rows in a `div`, set the row to `display:contents` and give it a background color (something like `myRowClass:nth-child(2n+1)`. Then in the 'data cells' of the table, set the background color to 'inherit'.